# What features are available in a cordova web view?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

What features (HTML, JS, CSS, Web APIs), outside of plugins, are available in a cordova web view ? I am making a web app, and then I use cordova to create an apk file. The web app works fine with chrome and firefox for android. But when I try the generated apk on the same android device and the emulator the JavaScript is obviously not executed because buttons have no effect.

The initial HTML and CSS display fine, and I think I use some JavaScript or HTML5 features that are not available yet on cordova web view, but I don't know what I can use and what I cannot. I had a look at the emulator's error log but I get nothing meaning-full.

For example is it possible to use es2015 without transpiling, esModules etc, but I don't know where to look it up. What is the difference between a webview browser and chrome/firefox for android.

Targeting Android 4 and later.

https://cordova.apache.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easiest to look at the architecture diagram: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/overview/index.html.

Cordova apps consist of a small wrapper around a WebView (this is a "window" of the default browser installed by your mobile OS, although you can swap it out for another: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/webviews/), with access to the mobile device's features via plugins. So... to answer your questions:

- You can use any technology that's supported by the mobile browser you're working in. https://caniuse.com is super helpful in this regard.
- You will also find that Android 4.x's stock web browser is not that great -- some of the shiny new popover UI stuff (walkthrough help and light boxes) will render, but the z-order is all messed up when you try to click to the next item. I've run into other issues as well, but I can't remember them off the top of my head.
- The [Crosswalk project](https://crosswalk-project.org) allows you to embed a Chrome browser web view in older Android versions (back to 4.x I think). Support for this project has been discontinued in the latest Cordova releases, as it's no longer necessary.